# Best way to check for common passwords ? (best practice and performance wise)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, security, passwords

I am currently working/learning on a **Node.js** website which will have users from various countries, while implementing user registeration I wanted to try protecting myself and users from attacks, but what I did so far seems overkill :

I took passwords from this source : https://www.openwall.com/mirrors/ (the worldwide one), took lower versions of each languages available (reunited them into one file) and removed duplicated entries. Total word count is approx. **2.8M** and leads to "**Maximum call stack size exceeded**"

So obviously it seems that is not the way to do it, I know they are middleware/services that can do it for me and I don't want to avoid them, I just don't know which one is "**worldwide**" and does not sacrifice performance too much
(For information I currently use [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) for form validation)

**EDIT :** Since my code was asked here is the main issue (imo):

```js
let commonPasswords;
    
fs.promises.readFile("static/commonPasswords.txt")
.then((result) => {
commonPasswords = result.toString().split(/\r?\n/);
})
.catch(err => console.log("Error while setting common passwords:", err));

const validateUserRegisteration = (user) => {
  if (commonPasswords.length > 0) {
    const userRegisteration = Joi.object({
      username: Joi.string().min(3).max(20).required(),
      email: Joi.string().email(),
      password: Joi.string().min(8).max(64).not(...commonPasswords),
      confirmPassword: Joi.ref('password')
    });
    return userRegisteration.validate(user);
  } else {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

**EDIT2**: I ended checking "manually" my passwords, in order (and only if previous succeed):

1. Using [dropbox password strength package](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) (thanks to [imvain2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3684265/imvain2))
2. "Manually" checking if password is in my commonPasswords list (which is now a set)
3. Calling userRegisteration.validate(user)

Comment: I would recommend against checking a password's content and focus on enforcing password length.

Comment: Look in to password entropy. With a 30 bit entropy password, it would take a very long time for a brute attack to find the password of a user. If security is a concern focus more so on protecting against injection attacks and csrf

Comment: "Maximum call stack size exceeded" is about the size of your stack and not memory used by a word list. In other words, you probably have runaway recursion or something like that. If you share your code, it might be possible to get it working. Although I think you'd likely be better off enforcing length and/or complexity.

Comment: I mostly agree, but this seems not enough, we can't let users have passwords like "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" or "qwertyuiop" (I am sticking to 2020 NIST guidelines https://blog.stealthbits.com/nist-password-guidelines/ )

Comment: You could continue your existing method but simply have a password file for each language instead of a massive one with all languages. Also for US/En at least, Dropbox developed and uses https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn